# How to find string containing regex special chars with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the fallowing piece of code :

```
details =~ /.#{action.name}.*/
```

If `action.name` contains regular string such as "abcd" then everything goes ok , 
but if `action.string` contains special chars such as `.` or `/` ,im getting an exception.

Is there a way to check the `action.name` string without having to put `\` before every special char inside action.name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape all special characters using [Regexp::escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape%5C).

Try:

```
details =~ /.#{Regexp.escape(action.name)}.*/
```